# Form not loading properly in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am having trouble getting my form to load, not sure why this is happening.

**THE PROBLEM:** When I try to load the form (/messages/new), I get a blank page, no error messages.

**REASON FOR THE PROBLEM:** I think the problem is that the link between message and user is not being properly established, that's why the form isn't loading properly, but not sure how to fix it.

**BACKGROUND:** I currently access the form through POSTS/INDEX file (attached below), but I think this is wrong because there should be a unique link for each user...e.g. if I click on the 'Contact' button for a post created by John, the message should go to John, and so on so forth for other users. I am using the Simple Private Messaging plugin.

Grateful for any feedback!

Thanks,

Faisal

**MESSAGES>NEW VIEW**

```
<% form_for @message, :url => messages_path(:user_id => @user) do |f| %>
<p>
To:<br />
<%= f.text_field :to %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
</p>
<p>
Subject:<br />
<%= f.text_field :subject %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
</p>
<p>
Message<br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= submit_tag "Send" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to

end
```

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :messages do
   collection do
     post :delete_selected
     end
   end

resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :pages
resources :posts

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
 @user = User.first
end
end
```

**POSTS>INDEX VIEW**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td>I am a <%= post.title %> getting married in <%= post.job %> in <%= post.location %>, and looking for a <%= post.salary %>. My budget is <%= post.salary %>.</td>
<td> <button class="btn" data-toggle="button" onClick="javascript:location.href = '/messages/new';" />Contact</button></td>
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</td>
<!--/. 
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
-->
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

messages/new line 1, try changing the opening ERB tag from a silent to loud tag

s/<%/<%=

sourced from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: thanks!!! it works..but for some reasons if i access /messages/new independent of any user (i.e. directly), the page still opens..how do i disable that?

Comment: Type `ActionController::Redirecting` into http://api.rubyonrails.org for some documentation on what you need to do to redirect users away from that page if you don't want them to access it